# How does the sinatra hello world example work?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, dsl

Where is the 'get' method defined? And how is it called on no object?

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

The example from the http://www.sinatrarb.com/ homepage.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624136/how-does-sinatra-define-and-invoke-the-get-method - also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917811/what-is-main-in-ruby in addition you should note that `get` is defined `private`, so to see it you need to do something like `p self.private_methods` just before the `get` call - then you will see what's defined output when you run `ruby hi.rb`

Answer (score 4):

You are not calling anything on "no object" but calling `require 'sinatra'` on `Object` and this loads the library, if it is available to be loaded, which gives you the method `get`, among other things.

Where get is defined is in the Sinatra gem, in the lib folder, in a file called base.rb and this code is presumably on your computer.

```
# Defining a `GET` handler also automatically defines
# a `HEAD` handler.
def get(path, opts = {}, &block)
  conditions = @conditions.dup
  route('GET', path, opts, &block)

  @conditions = conditions
  route('HEAD', path, opts, &block)
end
```

In order to understand what is going on here, you need a fundamental understanding of how Ruby works.  That is a bit more than what can or should be answered in an answer here.