# Method definition in ruby (like sinatra)

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I do not know where Sinatra methods (like `get` or `params`) are defined. According to `base.rb`, they are static parts of Sinatra's `Base` class. How can I call them anywhere by just writing `get`? Shouldn't I write something like `Sinatra::Base.get` instead? And how can I define things like that by myself?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624136/how-does-sinatra-define-and-invoke-the-get-method

Comment: A little reverse engineering and you'll get your answers... https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers can be found here: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/main.rb

When you do Sinatra in its simple mode, all methods like `get` or `set` or `post` are delegated through Sinatra::Delegator, which is defined here: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1977 and is mixed into global scope inside main.rb

Leaving all Sinatra tricks alone, for your own module you can achieve the effect with really simple code:

```ruby
module MyMixin
  def testme
    puts 'testme'
  end
end

extend MyMixin

testme # => testme
```